# Using Meteor.wrapAsync to wrap a callback inside a method

Tags: meteor

This Meteor code is giving the error:

> Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.

I tried `Meteor.bindEnvironment` for no avail and want to try Meteor.wrapAsync. I could not figure it out from the [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#wrap-async). Could some one please help me with the syntax? thx

```js
Meteor.methods({
'createTransaction':
    function (nonceFromTheClient, Payment) {
      let user = Meteor.user();
      gateway.transaction.sale(
        {
          arg_object
        },
          function (err, success) {
            if (!err) {
              //do stuff here
            }
          }

      );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap in Meteor.wrapAsync

```
Meteor.methods({
'createTransaction':
    function (nonceFromTheClient, Payment) {
      this.unblock();
      let user = Meteor.user();
      var sale = Meteor.wrapAsync(gateway.transaction.sale);
      var res = sale({arg_object});
      future.return(res);
      return future.wait();
    }
});
```

Or try wrapping it in Fiber

```
var Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');
Meteor.methods({
'createTransaction': function (nonceFromTheClient, Payment) {
    Fiber(function() {
      let user = Meteor.user();
      gateway.transaction.sale(
        {
          arg_object
        },
          function (err, success) {
            if (!err) {
              //do stuff here
            }
          }
      );
   }).run()
  }
});
```

Update: Here's how I handle stripe with Async.runSync and Meteor.bindEnvironment

```js
var stripe = require("stripe")(Meteor.settings.private.StripeKeys.secretKey);

Meteor.methods({
    'stripeToken': function() {
        this.unblock();
        var future = new Future();
        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(Meteor.userId(), userIdEncryptionToken);
        future.return(encrypted.toString());
        return future.wait();
    },
    'stripePayment': function(token) {
        var userId = Meteor.userId();
        var totalPrice = 0;
        //calculate total price from collection
        totalPrice = Math.ceil(totalPrice * 100) / 100;
        userEmail = Meteor.users.findOne({
            '_id': userId
        }).emails[0].address;

        // Create a charge: this will charge the user's card
        var now = new Date();
        Async.runSync(function(done) {
            var charge = stripe.charges.create({
                amount: Math.ceil(totalPrice * 100), // Amount in cents // coverting dollars to cents
                currency: "usd",
                source: token,
                receipt_email: userEmail,
                description: "Charging"
            }, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, charge) {
                if (err) {
                    //handle errors with a switch case for different errors     
                    done();
                } else {
                    //handle res, update order
                }
            }));
        }); // Async.runSync
    },
});
```

Comment: In the first code block using wrapAsync, does the `{arg_object}` contains the callback of the `gateway.transaction.sale` as well? Also How to deal with `future` since it is unresolved variable?

Comment: I also tried the second code block but still get the same error.

Comment: `arg_object` does not include a callback, because you are wrapping it asynchronously. You handle the method return in the same way as a regular method with a callback. `Meteor.call('createTransaction',nonce,payment,function(err,res){...})`

Comment: I am gonna update the answer with how I handle stripe payments